# NameNode DataNode communication on read operation

Tags: hadoop, communication

So I'm studying for the CCDH certification, and I found some sample questions online but to be honest, I don't think they are all that accurate so I would like to check here.

Which of the following describes best the read operation on HDFS?

A. The client queries the NameNode for the block location(s). The NameNode returns the
block location(s) to the client. The client reads the data directory off the DataNode(s).

B. The client queries all DataNodes in parallel. The DataNode that contains the requested
data responds directly to the client. The client reads the data directly off the DataNode.

C. The client contacts the NameNode for the block location(s). The NameNode then
queries the DataNodes for block locations. The DataNodes respond to the NameNode,
and the NameNode redirects the client to the DataNode that holds the requested data
block(s). The client then reads the data directly off the DataNode.

D. The client contacts the NameNode for the block location(s). The NameNode contacts
the DataNode that holds the requested data block. Data is transferred from the DataNode
to the NameNode, and then from the NameNode to the client.

I know for sure that B and D. According to the document, the correct answer is C. But I always thought that the NameNode already had the block locations in RAM, and did not need to query the datanodes? So I would expect the correct answer to be A. Am I wrong or is the document wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NameNode doesn't query DataNodes in order to get the block locations. Instead it builds it dynamically with the help of `block reports` sent by DNs. Remember, DNs send block reports after every few seconds to the NN along with heartbeats.

So, the correct answer should be option A.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why namenode seldom communicates with the datanodes is that, its major work is to provide read/write requests to the client and update the metadata from datanodes, hence it doesnt waste its resources and time fetching data from datanodes. Instead datanodes communicate with namenode which is simple socket based communication to provide heartbeat and block reports. Refer http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2014/05/multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-oracle.html.

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer should be option A.

NN-> Client - NN stores all file names, block locations in memory and responds to the client with required information.

NN->DN -- this seems invalid, because in Hadoop(Cheap hardware), DN sometimes unavailable(due to network or hardware issues) in the cluster, so NN should not depend on DD for metdata.

Hope this helps.